# Find $\text{dist}(i,A)$ where $A = \{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z-(1-i)|<1\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I am trying to find $\text{dist}(i,A)$ where $A = \{z\in\mathbb{C}:d(z,(1-i))<1\}$ where $d$ is the usual metric on $\mathbb{C}$, that is d(x,y) = |y-x|.

I know that the set A in the complex plane is the circle with radius $1$ centered at $(1-i)$ without its boundary.

Then we can express the squared distance between $i = (0,1)$ and the points $(x,y)$ in $A$ as, $$d((0,1),z)=x^2+(y+1)^2$$ Now clearly the distance will be minimum on the boundary (we need not worry that the boundary is not included in A since we are looking for the $\inf$ of the distance). So we have the additional restriction on $(x,y)$:
$$(x-1)^2+(y+1)^2 = 1$$

Now we can find the minimum distance using Lagrange multipliers for instance.

This route however seems like too much work, and so I ask if is there an easier way to find the distance?

Comment: Find a lower bound using the reverse triangle inequality

Comment: I could be wrong (I often am, in fact) and I have no good reason to believe this, but it might be the intersection of the circle and the line connecting $i$ and $1 - i$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom could you elaborate?

Comment: $|x-i| \geq | |x-(1-i)|-|(1-i)-i||$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest path from a point ${\bf p}$ to a circle $C$ is the line connecting ${\bf p}$ to the center of $C$.

To expand on my comment, here's a picture.

[image]

Let's say the center of $C$ is the point ${\bf q}$, and say that $C$ has radius $r$. I contend that $R$ is the shortest distance from ${\bf p}$ to the circle $C$. Let's say we draw some other line to circle $C$, and call its length $R'$. The triangle inequality immediately tells us that the straight path from ${\bf p}$ to ${\bf q}$ is less than taking the path to the other point on $C$, then to ${\bf q}$, so that

$$R + r < R' + r,$$

and $R < R'$.

Since the distance from $1 - i$ to $i$ is $\sqrt5$, and the circle has radius $1$, meaning that distance must be $\sqrt{5} - 1$ (which, coincidentally, is twice the reciprocal of the golden ratio!).